# How to make param required in NestJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I would like to make my route `Query` parameter required.
If it is missing I expect it to throw 404 HTTP error.

```ts
@Controller('')
export class AppController {
  constructor() {}
  @Get('/businessdata/messages')
  public async getAllMessages(
    @Query('startDate', ValidateDate) startDate: string,
    @Query('endDate', ValidateDate) endDate: string,
  ): Promise<string> {
   ...
  }
}
```

I'm using [NestJs pipes](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes) to determine if a parameter is valid, but not if it exists And I'm not sure that Pipes are made for that.

So how can I check in NestJS if my param exists if not throw an error?

Comment: Did you find a solution?  It seems like it's not possible within the framework.  Looks like you'd have to write a custom Pipe to do it?

Comment: Yes I have finally a pipe that do check it if empty or not

Comment: Can you plz provide your solution to check for missing parameter ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `class-validator`. Pipes are definitely made for that !

Example :
 **create-user.dto.ts**

```
import { IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateUserDto {
   @IsNotEmpty()
   password: string;
}
```

For more information see `class-validator` documentation :
https://github.com/typestack/class-validator

And NestJS Pipes & Validation documentation :
https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation

Comment: Can you use this approach for `@Query` parameters though.  These would only be strings.  


`@Get() getName( @Query name: string) { return name}`

Comment: If not providing the password value you will now get a 500 error, so how can we handle this case?

Comment: The  @IsNotEmpty() Decorator is made to check if the value is empty or null but he doesn't check for a missing parameter

Answer (score 12):

NestJS does not provide a decorator (like `@Query`) that detects undefined
value in `request.query[key]`.

You can write [custom decorator](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators) for that:

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common'

export const QueryRequired = createParamDecorator(
  (key: string, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest()

    const value = request.query[key]

    if (value === undefined) {
      throw new BadRequestException(`Missing required query param: '${key}'`)
    }

    return value
  }
)
```

Then use `@QueryRequired` decorator as you would use `@Query`:

```
@Get()
async someMethod(@QueryRequired('requiredParam') requiredParam: string): Promise<any> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This should be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

There hava a easy way to valide you parameter, https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Phi's answer, you can combine the use of `class-validator` with the following global validation pipe:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      /*
            If set to true, instead of stripping non-whitelisted 
            properties validator will throw an exception.
      */
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
      /*
            If set to true, validator will strip validated (returned) 
            object of any properties that do not use any validation decorators.
      */
      whitelist: true,
    }),
  );
```

I use this in order to only allow parameters defined in the DTO class so that it will throw an error when unknown parameters are sent with the request!

In Phie's example, a post request with a body like `{password: 'mypassword'}` will pass the validation when `{password: 'mypassword', other: 'reject me!'}` won't.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a DTO like you would for a `@Body`, instead of listing all the query params in the function args, like so:

```js
@Get('/businessdata/messages')
public async getAllMessages(
  @Query() getAllMessagesDto: GetAllMessagesDto
): Promise<string> {
  console.log(getAllMessagesDto.endDate) // etc
}
```

And define your DTO with your requirements like so:

```js
import { IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export class GetAllMessagesDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  startDate: Date;
  
  @IsNotEmpty()
  endDate: Date;
}
```

You can check [this doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation) to see details about how to add validators to your DTO, and in your case don't forget to add `forbidNonWhitelisted` if you want to refuse values that are not expected.